# PDF to Excel conversion putting each pdf page in a different worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, pdf-conversion

I am attempting to convert a pdf file (with 16 pages) to an excel file in order to run a program I already have in place in excel.  I have a code that converts the pdf to excel already, but I would like the macro to put each separate page of the pdf file in a different worksheet in my excel file( currently it copies all of the pages and pastes page 1 of the pdf into a worksheet).

All of the pages have the same heading if that helps at all.  My current code is included below, thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 'Declare Variable(s)
Dim appAA As Acrobat.CAcroApp, docPDF As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc
Dim strFileName As String, intNOP As Integer, arrI As Variant
Dim intC As Integer, intR As Integer, intBeg As Integer, intEnd As Integer

'Initialize Variables
Set appAA = CreateObject("AcroExch.App"): Set docPDF = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")

'Set PDF FileName  
strFileName = "C:\Documents and Settings\Michael Palkovitz\My Documents\Test\EC Operations Budget February FY13.pdf"

'Read PDF File
docPDF.Open (strFileName)

'Extract Number of Pages From PDF File
intNOP = docPDF.GetNumPages

'Select First Data Cell
Range("A1").Select

'Open PDF File
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink strFileName, , True

'Loop Through All PDF File Pages
For intC = 1 To intNOP
'Go To Page Number
SendKeys ("+^n" & intC & "{ENTER}")

'Select All Data In The PDF File's Active Page
SendKeys ("^a"), True

'Right-Click Mouse
SendKeys ("+{F10}"), True

'Copy Data As Table
SendKeys ("c"), True

'Minimize Adobe Window
SendKeys ("%n"), True

'Paste Data In This Workbook's Worksheet
ActiveSheet.Paste

'Select Next Paste Cell
Range("A" & Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row + 2).Select

'Maximize Adobe Window
SendKeys ("%x")
Next intC

'Close Adobe File and Window
SendKeys ("^w"), True

'Empty Object Variables
Set appAA = Nothing: Set docPDF = Nothing

'Select First Cell
Range("A1").Select
end sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](http://www.myengineeringworld.net/2012/07/vba-macro-to-open-pdf-file.html). You should be able to make a loop and extract each pages of your PDF in different worksheet.

Comment: Thanks for the help... the code runs without error, but upon opening the pdf.. i get a "the file name, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect" message.my pdf file path is as follows   
PDFPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "C:\Documents and Settings\Michael Palkovitz\My Documents\Test\EC Operations Budget February FY13.pdf"

Comment: Update.. I got your code to open the document, just need to get it to copy and paste.